# Can each application have a separate merchant account?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I work for a software company that is just starting to develop for the iPhone and we have a few clients that each want their own app developing and adding to the Market to sell.

My question... is it possible to create 'sub accounts' for each client so that they have access to information for their app and payments will go straight to them?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just create the account in the client's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We set up separate iTunes Connect accounts for the clients so that the client gets all of the info they need and also the money from Apple where applicable.

You would also need to set up Apple developer Accounts for each client (You get them to pay for their developer accounts) They can then add you to that dev account and you will be able to manage the provisioning, certificates and other things on their behalf but using your developer access account.

Apple documents this thoroughly here:

- [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)